# Authenticate using asp.net membership and facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on allowing users to log into my site using either facebook or the standard asp.net membership.

I am using the c# facebook sdk.

The first time the user logs into the site using facebook I create a new user in the membership database using their facebook id as their username and generate a random password.

So all is good I have created the new user account however I am not sure how to authenticate the logged in user against my membership database.

Within FormsAuthentication I can see a method to authenticate

```
 FormsAuthentication.Authenticate()
```

It requires name and password.

Can I authenticate the user against my membership database without knowing the password? I don't want to know the password so I need to ensure a random one is always generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if that's your case but maybe SetAuthCookie() method will solve your problem.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie.aspx